# Is it possible to remove panning for android map view pinch zoom?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps

I need to remove panning from mapview pinch zoom.

Is it possible?

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense... try being more specific about what exactly you want to do.  Do you want to prevent panning of the map, or pinch-to-zoom, or both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually the pinch zoom zooms in/out on the center point between your 2 fingers. Thats all it does and you cannot prevent it from doing otherwise.